# image along text

Tags: html, css, image

I have to put on site some info about using form with fancy graphic buttons.
I want it to go like this:

```
To show info press <info buttton icon>, to configure preferences press <preferences button icon>.
```

And icons are arranged in one big file icon by icon.
So for example `<info buttton icon>` is from icons.png file and have offset (20px, 20px) and `<preferences button icon>` are from the same file and have offset (20px, 40px).
I can use pure HTML and CSS.
I tried to use `div` with `background-position` property, but `div` cannot be inside paragraph.

I will be greatfull for any solutions or hints how to achieve this.

EDIT:
After reading response I have used following code:

```
<p>To show info press 
<span style="background: url(./img/icons.png); height: 18px; width: 18px;"></span>
, to configure preferences press 
<span style="background: url(./img/icons.png); height: 18px; width: 18px; background-position: -18px 0px !important;"></span></p>
<img src="./img/icons.png">
```

Icons in spans are not shown (spans are not visible, just text), but there are shown in `img` tag, so path to image is correct.

Comment: Use `span` instead of `div`

Comment: @Uby - Can you tell me how to use `span` to achieve result. I have updated my answer with my span based solution, but it is not working.

Comment: I just posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
<p>To show info press 
<span style="background: url(./img/icons.png); height: 18px; width: 18px; display:inline-block"></span>
, to configure preferences press 
<span style="background: url(./img/icons.png); height: 18px; width: 18px; background-position: -18px 0px !important; display:inline-block"></span></p>
<img src="./img/icons.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Paragraph never support a inside a div so u can us other inline group tag like span, label, em.....